# Oracle SQL COUNT in an EXISTS SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a query where I get all posts from my table INV where the INNUM exists more than 2 times in table INVS.
This is my query right now, but it fails with the typical "missing right parenthesis" error.
But when I run the EXISTS Query isolated, it works....

```
SELECT WO.WONUM, WO.DESCRIPTION, INV.INNUM, INV.STATUSDATE
     FROM INV LEFT OUTER JOIN WO ON INV.WOID = WO.WOID
     WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INVS WHERE INVS.INNUM = INV.INNUM and INVS.SITEID='ARZ' GROUP BY INVS.INNUM
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 ORDER BY INVS.INNUM
     );
```

I dont really know why!?

Comment: Remove `ORDER BY`in the subquery, this is not required and not a *valid syntax*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . use a scalar subquery to calculate the count and compare to "2" in the outer query:

```
SELECT WO.WONUM, WO.DESCRIPTION, INV.INNUM, INV.STATUSDATE
FROM INV LEFT OUTER JOIN
     WO
     ON INV.WOID = WO.WOID
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM INVS
       WHERE INVS.INNUM = INV.INNUM AND
             INVS.SITEID = 'ARZ' 
      ) > 2;
```

Your query is relying on a doubly nested correlation clause which Oracle does not support.

You could also move the subquery to the `FROM` clause, but this version is more in the spirit of how you have written the query.

Comment: Thanks!
That worked. It´s so much easier when you see the solution in front of you  :)

Answer (score 0):

You get `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` while using the `ORDER BY`clause in the subquery.

Remove it and you get a valid syntax

Example

```
with tab as (select rownum id from dual connect by level <= 5
union all
select 3 from dual union all
select 5 from dual)
select * from tab t
where exists
(select count(*) from tab 
 where id = t.id
 group by id
 having count(*) > 1)
;

        ID
----------
         3
         5
         3
         5
```

This is not a valid syntax --> `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

```
select * from tab t
where exists
(select count(*) from tab 
 where id = t.id
 group by id
 having count(*) > 1 order by id)
```